Running xUnit tests of the same class in parralel in Visual Studio with Resharper
I'm running my xUnit tests in Visual Studio with Resharper. I design my tests to be independent. I've setup parralelism in Resharper options. Yet, tests within a same class don't run in parralel. I could have one class per test but that would be heavy.
Is there a solution to setup xUnit and Resharper to run tests within a same class (or even within a same Theory) in parralel?
